# How to increase width for modal custom mean no lg-md-sm responsive?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V8U9.png)I mean how to custom resize the width of modal with responsive .I custom the width with media query .But when size decreases for screen it move slight to left . But when refresh it again centered.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7rdM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have to do this for every size:

```css
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .yourClassName {
       max-width: 300px;
       margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```